# Iterating over Selenium WebDriver Browser Element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have selected a portion of a website to scrape data with xpath which works perfectly fine with this command:

`artistNames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="divAuctionRecords"]/div[position()>=1 and position()<=1100]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a')`

I have created an empty list
all_artists_names = [] and
a validator/parameter called artist_param = "Artist"

```
I used a for loop to loop through and assign data to various lists but I keep getting 
TypeError: argument of type 'WebElement' is not iterable
```

This is my for loop:

```
    for med in range(len(artistNames)):
        if artist_param in artistNames[med]:
           all_artists_names.append(artistMedium[med].text)
        elif auction_param in artistMedium[med]:
            all_artists_auction.append(artistMedium[med].text)
        else:
            all_artists_medium[med].append(" ")
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: for which line you are getting this error

Comment: @PDHide It is just printing this error on the first iteration for this type of syntax. I can't jump over that for which I have multiple of them too

Comment: is it throwing it in the the for loop , the stack trace will have information on which line its throwing

Comment: ae you sure for artistNames u used find_elements and not find_element

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-ba20aa83f271> in <module>
     42 
     43 for hs in range(len(artistsHammer_SalesP)):
---> 44     if sales_param in artistsHammer_SalesP[hs]:
     45         all_artists_sales.append(artistsHammer_SalesP[hs].text)
     46     else:

TypeError: argument of type 'WebElement' is not iterable            


@PDHide This is my error on Jupyter Notebook

Comment: You are getting error in artistsHammer_SalesP[hs]: , your question doenst have these elements at all

Comment: This is what I have on my list:
`artistsHammer_SalesP = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="divAuctionRecords"]/div[position()>=1 and position()<=1100]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]')` 

@PDHide

Comment: what is hs in that what are you trying to do

Comment: if sales_param in artistsHammer_SalesP[hs]:   what are you trying to do here

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that anytime you want to loop through a webELement as well as specifying a condition, this syntax can help you:

```
for variable_name in range(len(variable_from_webElement_extract)):
    if parameter_you_want_to_set in variable_from_webElement_extract[variable_name].text:
        new_list_to_append_values.append(variable_from_webElement_extract[variable_name].text)
    else:
        other_list_to_hold_other_values.append(variable_from_webElement_extract[variable_name].text)
```